# cannot convert to bool type

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I am new to C#. I am having problem with the conversion of bool type. I have my table tbl_Staff in which the IsActive column has type bit and i wanted to bind to the combox and send the data of cmbIsActive to tbl_Staff column IsActive but cannot define the type conversion of bit.Please help.

Following are the codes for my procedure and solutions.

Table definition tbl_Staff

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Staff](
    [StaffID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [JoinedDate] [date] NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stored Procedure : sp_ManageUser

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ManageUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StaffIDId int,
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @Address nvarchar(500),
    @Phone nvarchar(100),
    @Email nvarchar(100),
    @JoinedDate date,
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(max),
    @CreatedDate date,
    @IsActive bit,
    @Mode varchar(1)
     AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if(@Mode='I')
    insert into tbl_Staff       (Name,Address,Phone,Email,JoinedDate,Username,Password,CreatedDate,IsActive)values(@Name,@Address,@Phone,@Email,@JoinedDate,@Username,@Password,@CreatedDate,@IsActive)
if(@Mode='U')
Update tbl_Staff set Name=@Name,Address=@Address,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,JoinedDate=@JoinedDate,Username=@Username,Password=@Password,CreatedDate=@CreatedDate,IsActive=@IsActive where StaffID=@StaffIDId
if(@Mode='D')
Delete from tbl_Staff where StaffID=@StaffIDId
end
```

Codes for save button

```
private void btnSaveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PSMBusinessLogicClass pblc = new PSMBusinessLogicClass();
            UserClass uc = new UserClass();
            try
            {
                bool result = uc.ManageUser(txtFullName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerJoinedDate),txtUserame.Text, txtPassword.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerCreatedDate),cmbIsActive, "I");
                if (result == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("New Project Saved");
                    dgvUserDetails.DataSource = uc.SelectAllUsers();
                    //MakeFieldsBlank();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SOME ERRORS OCCURED WHILE PROCESSING THE REQUEST");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

UserClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace PSMDataAccessLayer
{
    public class UserClass
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataConnectionClass.DbConnection);
        public int ManageUser( String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, DateTime JoinedDate, String Username, String Password, DateTime CreatedDate, Boolean IsActive, String Mode)
        {
            try
            {
                int result = 0;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ManageUser", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JoinedDate", JoinedDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", CreatedDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", IsActive);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mode", Mode);
                conn.Open();
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public DataTable SelectAllUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Staff", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                conn.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public int Login(String Username, String Password)
        {
            try
            {
                int result = 0;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Staff where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                conn.Close();
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    result = 1;
                else
                    result = 0;
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do two things: Take the [tour], read at least [ask] and then create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

`Convert.ToBoolean(value)` - will convert your value to boolean.

So your code should look like this.

> bool result = uc.ManageUser(txtFullName.Text, txtAddress.Text,
>   txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text,
>   Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerJoinedDate),txtUserame.Text,
>   txtPassword.Text,
>   Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerCreatedDate),Convert.ToBoolean(cmbIsActive.SelectedValue),
>   "I");

I do not know what is this `cmbIsActive` my guess that it is combobox. So you need to retrieve selected value before calling to function `Convert.ToBoolean`

Comment: Hi,Thank You for your suggestion Convert.ToBoolean(value) ,but now it shows Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'. I have gone through couple of blogs but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I think I have found it
bool result = uc.ManageUser( -this function returns int but you are expecting to receive boolean
Or int result = uc.ManageUser( or return convert.ToBoolean(result);

Comment: If you would like i could provide you with the full project.Please look into these files. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1N0pl3MPbi6UnpuT3ZUWnVfbmc&usp=sharing

Thanking You,

Comment: As I mentioned the problem is in return type of function ManageUser 
This function returns int value but you are expecting to boolean value.  **bool** result = uc.ManageUser( <- here you are returning **int** from ManageUser but your **result** variable is boolean, it can not be done this way and will fall down on implicitly convert.
Two options is: 1. Return boolean from function ManageUser 2. change **bool result** to **int result**

Comment: As you mentioned i changed bool result to int result and it fixed the error. Thank you for your help. I am currenlty in final year of BScIT and this is my college project. Hope you would help in future too.
Thanking YOu,

Comment: Hello, I am again some error with the procedure and code. I cannot save staff details from the form as it shows error message : Procedure or function 'sp_ManageUser' expects parameter '@StaffID', which was not supplied. where StaffID is auto increament

Comment: Hi, your procedure expects to **@StaffIDId int** even though it auto increment. It even can be something like cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffIDId", DBNull.Value);

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,but it showed Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_Staff' when INDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF while inserting the records.

Comment: It means that you trying to insert value into auto incremental column, you do not need to do that. All you need is to pass value to the procedure if it's expects to the value but do not use it in insert query.